# Migrate Azure AD to a new subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an Azure AD which is managed by a third party.  Our domainname is validated against it.  We are now bringing this in-house and want to know the easiest way to move it?  It doesn't have many objects, so happy to recreate them but to do so, I need to validate our domain against this Azure AD instance.  If I do this, I am concerned it will break the existing which would be a problem as we have users using it.  Can you have a single domain validated against two directories (no on-prem integration).  Also, is there an easier option?  I don't mind users having to reset their password.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/c985b8ea-b799-421d-88b2-875d426b2158/move-azure-active-directory-to-on-premise-ad?forum=windowsazureaditpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have one domain name verified in two Azure AD tenants.

The title of this question indicates a common misunderstanding is at play here: Azure AD tenants are **not** resources within an Azure subscription. If anything, it's the other way around: an Azure subscription is associated to an Azure AD tenant. Read more on the relationship between an Azure subscription and an Azure AD tenant at "[How Azure subscriptions are associated with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory/)", and on how to transfer Azure subscriptions across Azure AD tenants at "[Transferring ownership of an Azure subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-subscription-transfer/)."

If there already exists an Azure AD tenant with your domain name, you should simply take control of the tenant. If you already have access to a user account that is a tenant administrator, then you simply need to evict (demote, disable or delete, depending on your situation) the users from the third party. If you don't, you can ask the third party to make your user an admin. (And if that is not possible either, you can contact support to prove ownership of the domain name.)

Comment: Thanks, will give this a rethink.  I will leave the question title as it was, hopefully will help others.